# I need a logic to implement Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a 3 tables:
1. Users -- here "userd id" is primary key
2. UserPermision --here  "userd id" is a foreign key and there is "pageid" coloumn
3. Page  -- here page id is a primary key

Now i need to write a query when i inser a new user say user id = "1" then this user id 1 should be inserted into Userpermision table and for this user it shouls have all the pages from page table .

Comment: One question: why do you need a permissionsystem if a user has all premission? I guess you should have a look at [INSERT TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: have you tried anything at all or just asking us to do your job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using InnoDB.
In that case you have foreign key constraints and transactions.

If not you'll have to use triggers.

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO users (name, etc) VALUES ('test', 'remainder');

SELECT last_insert_id() INTO @my_user_id;

INSERT INTO userpermission (userid, permission, pageid) 
  SELECT 
    @my_user_id as user_id
    , 'all' as permission
    , pageid 
  FROM pages 
  WHERE pages.userid = @my_user_id;

COMMIT;
```

This is assuming you've already made pages for that user.

**link**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Answer (score 0):

You need two INSERT queries, one for each table.

```
INSERT INTO Users (user_id,...) VALUES (:user_id,...)

INSERT INTO UserPermission (user_id,page_id)
SELECT :user_id, page_id FROM Page
```

You can either execute them within the same transaction, or execute the second one from the AFTER INSERT trigger on the Users table.

Comment: you normally do not assign explicit id's in a table, but let MySQL figure out an auto_increment id.

Comment: @Frazz: I have inserted new user in User table.. Now I need to insert same user in user permission table and I need to get all pages from page table for that particular user.  for eg if i have 5 pages then this user in permission table shouls have 5 page records.. here i am not able to write a query??